# jquerymobile adding a mention option from a json result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a panel with option and I have written a jsonp to get an array of items from a remote site. All that is fine and in the on success of the call I have added:

```
 success:function(cats){
     //alert("Success");
     console.log(cats);
     var len = Object.keys(cats).length
     for    (index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        var pl = "<li><a href=\"#\" class=\"menuoption\" data-rel=\"close\">"+cats[index]['category']+"</a></li>";
        //alert(pl);
        $("#catslist").append(pl);
     }
```

but instead of getting a nice series of buttons in common with jquery mobile standard I get a listing:

[image]

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Use class='ui-btn', if you are using this, <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

Comment: Forgot to add example: :  <button class="ui-btn">Button</button>

Comment: Thanks Neeraj but all that happened was the list was centered. The jquery mobile style sheet is added and variable pl contains the write html as I added one manually and it formatted correctly.

Comment: can you add pi variable result set ?

Answer (score 0):

after appending you need to refresh listview using `$(list-view-container).listview( "refresh" );` [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aminkodaganur/c9pwnh7k/)

in your case do like this

```
for(index = 0; index < len; index++) {
    var pl = "<li><a href=\"#\" class=\"menuoption\" data-rel=\"close\">"+cats[index]['category']+"</a></li>";
    //alert(pl);
    $("#catslist").append(pl);
 }
$("#catslist").listview( "refresh" );
```

for more info [refer](https://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh)

Comment: Thanks Amin. If I add this as you have above I get only the first item but still unformatted, and if I put this at the end of the loop I get the full list but unformatted - as in the picture.

Comment: add it after your `for loop` and see

Comment: as I mentioned if I place if immediately after the loop it comes out as unfromatted but they are all listed.

Comment: Oh wait then let me add u jsfiddel for it

Comment: I can see that but it seems to not work if the data is brought in as a result of a jsonp call. I have tried many variations but I am getting nowhere. Also if I click on the links they do not close the panel.

Comment: I was too had same issue earlier but this fixied me.... can u please add your listview HTML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98908/discussion-between-user3613255-and-amin-kodaganur).